# Google Drive Api v3 - Filter response if mimetype is a folder

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to filter the response of google drive api. So if the `response.Files.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder` I want to do something with it, if not I want to do something else. The issue is I cannot think of a way to do this. I have something like this

```
do {
    var response = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    if (response.Files.Where(f => f.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")) {
        // error here
    }

    files.AddRange(response.Files.Where(f => f.Name != "$ExclaimerSignatures").Select(f => mapFile(f)));

    listRequest.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;

} while ( listRequest.PageToken != null );
```

I get a type conversion error of cannot convert Generic<Google.Apis.....> to 'bool' and I understand why this error is produced. But my brain cannot think of how to do it in any other way at the moment. I can't use .Any(f => f.MimeType....) because I want to do something specific if it is a folder. I know I am over thinking something simple but my brain is stuck haha

Comment: `var folders = response.Files.Where(f => f.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")`?

Comment: Interesting, then I basically just need to have the conditional check folders? I don't know why I did not think of this!